# Размер картинки в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу никак сделать так, чтобы картинки на слайдах были одного и того же размера и не изменяли размер во время прокрутки.

Вот код:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="images/universe.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img width="2000" height="800" class="cerousel-imeges" src="images/universe2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/universe3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
</div>
```

Может лучше задать им какой-нибудь класс и вынести отдельно в файла style.css ? Я пробовал - у меня не получается так. Не могли бы вы показать как это делается ?

Помимо всего сдвигаются кнопки выбора нужной картинки в самый низ страницы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `height: 800px !important;` если нужно именно так.

Например:

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<div class="container">
  <!-- Слайдер -->
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <!-- Активный индикатор-->
      <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <!-- Неактивные индикаторы -->
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Слайды -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
       <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
         <img src="http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cosmos-flowers-in-full-bloom-picture-id467213949?k=6&m=467213949&s=170667a&w=0&h=y5trnQg5YGRZ8hiJQdpHW3fI2QsyPk547IslOsA2zuQ=" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Или, на всякий случай, вариант с фоновыми картинками (чтобы изображения более красиво выглядели):

```css
.item-img {
  width: 600px; 
  height: 350px; 
  background-repeat: no-rpeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <!-- Слайдер -->
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Индикаторы слайдов -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <!-- Активный индикатор-->
      <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <!-- Неактивные индикаторы -->
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Слайды -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <div class="item-img" style="background-image: url(http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg);"></div>
        <!-- <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt=""> -->
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
         <div class="item-img" style="background-image: url(http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cosmos-flowers-in-full-bloom-picture-id467213949?k=6&m=467213949&s=170667a&w=0&h=y5trnQg5YGRZ8hiJQdpHW3fI2QsyPk547IslOsA2zuQ="></div>
       <!--  <img src="http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/cosmos-flowers-in-full-bloom-picture-id467213949?k=6&m=467213949&s=170667a&w=0&h=y5trnQg5YGRZ8hiJQdpHW3fI2QsyPk547IslOsA2zuQ=" alt=""> -->
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
         <div class="item-img" style="background-image: url(http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"></div>
       <!--  <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt=""> -->
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
          <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Стрелки переключения слайдов -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А не подскажите из-за чего могут быть смещены кнопки переключения картинки ? Пример того о чем я говорю приведен в дополнении к вопросу.

Comment: Нужно бы высоту во всех блоках слайдера проверить! Так не скажу, смотреть нужно